# Pandas sort multiple columns independently

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I've been struggling to sort the entire columns of my df, however, my code seems to be working for solely the first column ('Name') and shuffles the rest of the columns based upon the first column as shown here:

```
Index Name Age Education Country 
0    W    2    BS         C
1    V    1    PhD        F 
2    R    9    MA         A
3    A    8    MA         A
4    D    7    PhD        B
5    C    4    BS         C
```

`df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Age', 'Education', 'Country'],ascending=[True,True, True, True])`

Here's what I'm hoping to get:

```
Index Name Age Education Country 
0     A    1    BS         A
1     C    2    BS         A 
2     D    4    MA         B
3     R    7    MA         C
4     V    8    PhD        C
5     W    9    PhD        F
```

Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
Index Name Age Education Country 
3     A    8    MA         A
5     C    4    BS         C
4     D    7    PhD        B
2     R    9    MA         A
1     V    1    PhD        F 
0     W    2    BS         C
```

Could you please shed some light on this issue. Many thanks in advance.
Cheers,
R.

Comment: Your desired result changes data. Pandas or any reputable data science tool will never allow such a result.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your answer. Actually, my current dataframe doesnt really look like the one I posted. The purpose of my post was to learn how to sort each and every single column independently. My actual dataframe contains columns listing Organizations of several continents. So the columns correspond to continents like "Asia" "Europe "America" ...and under each of these headers there's a list of Organizations. Now I am hoping to get each column sorted alphabetically. So in my case, these columns are totally independent and there will be no mismatching

Comment: @Parfait. Hi Parfait. I was actually wondering why Pandas wouldn't will not allow such a thing, what if one desires to look at each column or have them sorted  separately?

Comment: @Riccardo...With data sets, rows mean something. They serve as distinct observations with values across diverse columns. By sorting each column *independently* you change the values within observations. For example, in your desired result, person *A* now has a different *Age* and *Education*!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is sorting by name, then age, then country, etc.

To get what you want, you can do sort for **each column** to sort column by column. For example,

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=sorted(df[col])
```

But are you sure that’s what you want to do? DataFrame is designed so that each row corresponds to a single entry, e.g. a person, and the columns corresponds to attributes like, ‘name’ and ‘age’, etc. So you don’t want sort the name and age separately so that people’s name and age get mismatched.

Comment: This doesn't do want OP asked.

Comment: @Tim. Thanks for your answer. Actually, my current dataframe doesnt really look like the one I posted. The purpose of my post was to learn how to sort each and every single column independently. My actual dataframe contains columns listing Organizations of several continents. So the columns correspond to continets like "Asia" "Europe "America" ...and under each of these headers there's a list of Organizations. Now I am hoping to get each column sorted alphabetically. So in my case, these columns are totally independent and there will be no mismatching.

Comment: I did try your code, however, I'm getting the error below. `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'` . Once I do sorted(df['col1']) individually for the first column, it works fine, but it fails for the second column. Is that because I'm having a bunch of NaN in 2nd column?

Comment: Yes, you can do ‘sorted(df[col].astype(str))’ for columns with strings

Comment: To check if a column has strings, you can add a condition checking if df[col].dtype is object.

Comment: @Tim. Awesome! It's working just fine Tim. Appreciate your assistance! :)

Comment: @Tim. In Case I wanted to write each column in a new df, could you let me know, how do I go about creating an empty new_df dataframe right before this for loop you mentioned?    new_df[col] = sorted(df[col].astype(str))

Comment: You can simply do ‘new_df=pandas.DataFrame()’. That creates an empty df. Then, replace df[col] on left side of = with new_df[col]. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.sort` along the 0<sup>th</sup> axis:

```
df[:] = np.sort(df.values, axis=0)
df

   Index Name  Age Education Country
0      0    A    1        BS       A
1      1    C    2        BS       A
2      2    D    4        MA       B
3      3    R    7        MA       C
4      4    V    8       PhD       C
5      5    W    9       PhD       F
```

If course, you should beware that sorting columns independently will mess the order of your columns relative to one another and render your data meaningless.

Comment: A huge thanks to you. Could you let me know how your line of code would look like in case one is dealing with solely String entries. :)

Comment: @Riccardo Or did you mean you only want to sort the string columns (leaving the numeric columns as-is)?

Comment: Sure I will. Once I run your colde, here's what I'm getting `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'`, so I assume it may not be working for strings

Comment: @Riccardo There is a problem, your data has NaNs. Can you do something like `df = df.dropna()` before running this code? Or do you need to keep those rows with NaN?

Comment: Yea, right there are bunch of NaN s in there, however,  don't need them. Column 1 contains 333 rows (no NaN at all in this column), Column 2 (has NaN from row 44 all the way down to the of df, ie. row 333), column 3 (contains NaN from row 27 all the way down to end which is row 333). I did try dropna method, it discarded all rows after row 27 for all 3 columns. This is not what should be happening, it actually discarded all entries below row 27 for column 1 and 2 as well.

Comment: @Riccardo I don't know what your data looks like, but perhaps you can fill the NaNs with some default values? Check out [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna).

Comment: Well, `sorted(df[col].astype(str))’ ` is able to do the job as @Tom mentioned above. without having to deal with NaN entries.

Comment: @Riccardo `sorted` can deal with mixed data types but will probably not do a great job in terms of performance. It is up to you. If you feel Tim's answer works, you are free to go with it :)

Comment: Well, I'm also trying your way by doing dropna() on each and every single column, but newdf looks identical to df with all NaN untouched.                                                                                              `newdf = pd.DataFrame()`
    `for Col in df.columns:`
        `newdf[Col] = df[Col].dropna()`

Comment: @Riccardo It will not work like that. You can only apply the dropna operation on the entire DataFrame, not a column at a time

Comment: Thanks. In that case dropna() fails to work here since what it does is, its discarding the rest of columns below row 27 (This is where NaN s appear in column 3)