# generating random values and append the results in next columns

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

The first thing I want to do is get four numbers from the user and put them in the first column.(For example: 10,30,60,80)
Then I need to create another columns(second), in addition to the first column, and the rows of the second column should vary as shown below.

```
10  Values should range from 1-2
30 values should range from 3-4
60 values should range from 5-8
80 values should range from 3-8
```

Based on that I would like to generate `1000` data sets and save them as single file.
Expected output should be similar

```
10   1.2  1.5 ...
30   3.8  3.4 ...
60   5.8  5.2 ...
80   3.8  4.2 ...
```

Script:

```
import numpy as np
import random
inp_data=[10, 30, 60, 80]
random_data=np.random.uniform(1,2)
```

I got stuck here, Please help experts.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pandas and [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.uniform.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inp_data=[10, 30, 60, 80]

# mapping dict for the ranges
ranges = {10: [1,2],
          30: [3,4],
          60: [5,8],
          80: [3,8]
         }

# initialize random generator
rng = np.random.default_rng()

# load input data as dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(inp_data, columns=['inp_data'])
# apply random generator to input data column
random_df = df['inp_data'].apply(lambda x: rng.uniform(ranges[x][0], ranges[x][1], size=(1000))).apply(pd.Series)

random_df[:] = np.sort(random_df.values, axis=1) # this sorts the row, set axis=0 to sort column-wise
# join generated data with df and save as csv
df = df.join(random_df.round(3))
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Try `df = df.join(random_df.round(3))` to round on 3 digits.

Comment: Thanks once again @RJ Ad.. I am going to post another problem very soon.

Comment: Sure, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54739834/11380795)

Comment: Then sort `random_df` before joining?

Comment: Inserting `random_df[:] = np.sort(random_df.values, axis=0)` before the join works in my example.

Comment: Ok, see update.